pfsense trying to change the sort order of dhcp_leases
this file is from pfsense and is used among other things to display the dhcp leases ip addresses when you select STATUS / DHCP LEASES from the dashboard dropdown menu's.
By default it displays this table by IP address decending (highest ip addresses down to lowest ip addresses.  Previous versions of pfense used to sort in the opposite order (low to high), which is in most cases much more helpful way to look at the data.  Is it possible from this code to change the display order from H to L to Low to High?
    <?php
/*
 * status_dhcp_leases.php
 *
 * part of pfSense (https://www.pfsense.org)
 * Copyright (c) 2004-2013 BSD Perimeter
 * Copyright (c) 2013-2016 Electric Sheep Fencing
 * Copyright (c) 2014-2023 Rubicon Communications, LLC (Netgate)
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * originally based on m0n0wall (http://m0n0.ch/wall)
 * Copyright (c) 2003-2004 Manuel Kasper <mk@neon1.net>.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

##|+PRIV
##|*IDENT=page-status-dhcpleases
##|*NAME=Status: DHCP leases
##|*DESCR=Allow access to the 'Status: DHCP leases' page.
##|*MATCH=status_dhcp_leases.php*
##|-PRIV

require_once('guiconfig.inc');
require_once('config.inc');
require_once('system.inc');

$pgtitle = [gettext('Status'), gettext('DHCP Leases')];
$shortcut_section = 'dhcp';
if (dhcp_is_backend('kea')) {
    $shortcut_section = 'kea-dhcp4';
}

if (dhcp_is_backend('isc')):
if (($_POST['deleteip']) && (is_ipaddr($_POST['deleteip']))) {
    $leasesfile = "{$g['dhcpd_chroot_path']}/var/db/dhcpd.leases";

    /* Stop DHCPD */
    killbyname("dhcpd");

    /* Read existing leases */
    /* $leases_contents has the lines of the file, including the newline char at the end of each line. */
    $leases_contents = file($leasesfile);
    $newleases_contents = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < count($leases_contents)) {
        /* Find the lease(s) we want to delete */
        if ($leases_contents[$i] == "lease {$_POST['deleteip']} {\n") {
            /* Skip to the end of the lease declaration */
            do {
                $i++;
            } while ($leases_contents[$i] != "}\n");
        } else {
            /* It's a line we want to keep, copy it over. */
            $newleases_contents[] = $leases_contents[$i];
        }
        $i++;
    }

    /* Write out the new leases file */
    $fd = fopen($leasesfile, 'w');
    fwrite($fd, implode("\n", $newleases_contents));
    fclose($fd);

    /* Restart DHCP Service */
    services_dhcpd_configure();
    header("Location: status_dhcp_leases.php?all={$_REQUEST['all']}");
}
endif;

if (dhcp_is_backend('kea')):
if (($_POST['deleteip']) && (is_ipaddr($_POST['deleteip']))) {
    system_del_kea4lease($_POST['deleteip']);
}
endif;

if (dhcp_is_backend('isc')):
if ($_POST['cleardhcpleases']) {
    killbyname("dhcpd");
    sleep(2);
    unlink_if_exists("{$g['dhcpd_chroot_path']}/var/db/dhcpd.leases*");

    services_dhcpd_configure();
    header("Location: status_dhcp_leases.php?all={$_REQUEST['all']}");
}
endif;

if (dhcp_is_backend('kea')):
if ($_POST['cleardhcpleases']) {
    system_clear_all_kea4leases();
}
endif;

// Load MAC-Manufacturer table
$mac_man = load_mac_manufacturer_table();

include('head.inc');

display_isc_warning();

$leases = system_get_dhcpleases();

$arp_table = system_get_arp_table();
$arpdata_mac = array();
foreach ($arp_table as $arp_entry) {
    if (isset($arpentry['incomplete'])) {
        continue;
    }
    $arpdata_mac[] = $arp_entry['mac-address'];
}
unset($arp_table);

/*
 * Translate these once so we don't do it over and over in the loops
 * below.
 */
$online_string = gettext("active/online");
$active_string = gettext("active");
$expired_string = gettext("expired");
$dynamic_string = gettext("dynamic");
$static_string = gettext("static");

if ($_REQUEST['order']) {
    usort($leases['lease'], function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a[$_REQUEST['order']], $b[$_REQUEST['order']]);
    });
}

/* only print pool status when we have one */
if (count($leases['failover']) > 0):
?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title"><?=gettext('Pool Status')?></h2></div>
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed sortable-theme-bootstrap" data-sortable>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?=gettext("Failover Group")?></a></th>
                <th><?=gettext("My State")?></a></th>
                <th><?=gettext("Since")?></a></th>
                <th><?=gettext("Peer State")?></a></th>
                <th><?=gettext("Since")?></a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php foreach ($leases['failover'] as $data):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['name'])?></td>
                <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['mystate'])?></td>
                <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['mydate'])?></td>
                <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['partnerstate'])?></td>
                <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['partnerdate'])?></td>
            </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
/* only print pool status when we have one */
endif;
?>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="search-panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">
            <?=gettext('Search')?>
            <span class="widget-heading-icon pull-right">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#search-panel_panel-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="search-panel_panel-body" class="panel-body collapse in">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                <?=gettext('Search Term')?>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-control" name="searchstr" id="searchstr" type="text"/></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select id="where" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1" selected><?=gettext('All')?></option>
                    <option value="2"><?=gettext('Lease Type')?></option>
                    <option value="3"><?=gettext('Client Status')?></option>
                    <option value="4"><?=gettext('IP Address')?></option>
                    <option value="5"><?=gettext('MAC Address')?></option>
                    <option value="6"><?=gettext('Client ID')?></option>
                    <option value="7"><?=gettext('Hostname')?></option>
                    <option value="8"><?=gettext('Description')?></option>
                    <option value="9"><?=gettext('Start')?></option>
                    <option value="10"><?=gettext('End')?></option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <a id="btnsearch" title="<?=gettext("Search")?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-search icon-embed-btn"></i><?=gettext("Search")?></a>
                <a id="btnclear" title="<?=gettext("Clear")?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-undo icon-embed-btn"></i><?=gettext("Clear")?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <span class="help-block"><?=gettext('Enter a search string or *nix regular expression to filter entries.')?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title"><?=gettext('Leases')?></h2></div>
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed sortable-theme-bootstrap" data-sortable>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-sortable="false"><!-- icon --></th>
                    <th><?=gettext("IP Address")?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext("MAC Address")?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext("Hostname")?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext('Description')?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext("Start")?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext("End")?></th>
                    <th data-sortable="false"><?=gettext("Actions")?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="leaselist">
<?php
$dhcp_leases_subnet_counter = array(); //array to sum up # of leases / subnet
$iflist = get_configured_interface_with_descr(); //get interface descr for # of leases
$no_leases_displayed = true;

foreach ($leases['lease'] as $data):
    if ($data['act'] != $active_string && $data['act'] != $static_string && $_REQUEST['all'] != 1) {
        continue;
    }

    $no_leases_displayed = false;

    if ($data['act'] == $active_string) {
        /* Active DHCP Lease */
        $icon = 'fa-check-circle-o';
    } elseif ($data['act'] == $expired_string) {
        /* Expired DHCP Lease */
        $icon = 'fa-ban';
    } else {
        /* Static Mapping */
        $icon = 'fa-user';
    }

    if ($data['act'] != $static_string) {
        foreach ($config['dhcpd'] as $dhcpif => $dhcpifconf) {
            if (empty($dhcpifconf)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!is_array($dhcpifconf['range']) || !isset($dhcpifconf['enable'])) {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_inrange_v4($data['ip'], $dhcpifconf['range']['from'], $dhcpifconf['range']['to'])) {
                $data['if'] = $dhcpif;
                $dlskey = $dhcpif . "-" . $dhcpifconf['range']['from'];
                $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['dhcpif'] = $dhcpif;
                $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['from'] = $dhcpifconf['range']['from'];
                $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['to'] = $dhcpifconf['range']['to'];
                $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['count'] += 1;
                break;
            }

            // Check if the IP is in the range of any DHCP pools
            if (is_array($dhcpifconf['pool'])) {
                foreach ($dhcpifconf['pool'] as $dhcppool) {
                    if (is_array($dhcppool['range'])) {
                        if (is_inrange_v4($data['ip'], $dhcppool['range']['from'], $dhcppool['range']['to'])) {
                            $data['if'] = $dhcpif;
                            $dlskey = $dhcpif . "-" . $dhcppool['range']['from'];
                            $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['dhcpif'] = $dhcpif;
                            $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['from'] = $dhcppool['range']['from'];
                            $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['to'] = $dhcppool['range']['to'];
                            $dhcp_leases_subnet_counter[$dlskey]['count'] += 1;
                            break 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $mac = $data['mac'];
    $mac_hi = strtoupper($mac[0] . $mac[1] . $mac[3] . $mac[4] . $mac[6] . $mac[7]);
?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <i class="fa <?=$icon?> act" title="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['act'])?>"></i>
<?php if ($data['online'] === $online_string): ?>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up text-success online" title="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['online'])?>"></i>
<?php else: ?>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down online" title="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['online'])?>"></i>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['ip'])?></td>
<?php if ($data['cid']): ?>
                    <td style="cursor: help;" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-trigger="hover focus" data-content="<?=gettext('Client ID')?>: <span class=&quot;cid&quot;><?=$data['cid']?></span>" data-html="true" data-original-title="<?=gettext('DHCP Client Information')?>">
<?php else: ?>
                    <td>
<?php endif; ?>
                        <?=htmlspecialchars($mac)?>

                        <?php if (isset($mac_man[$mac_hi])):?>
                            (<?=htmlspecialchars($mac_man[$mac_hi])?>)
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['hostname'])?></td>
                    <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['descr'])?></td>
                    <? if ($data['type'] != $static_string): ?>
                        <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['starts'])?></td>
                        <td><?=htmlspecialchars($data['ends'])?></td>
                    <? else: ?>
                        <td><?=gettext("n/a")?></td>
                        <td><?=gettext("n/a")?></td>
                    <? endif; ?>
                    <td>
<?php if ($data['type'] == $dynamic_string): ?>
                        <a class="fa fa-plus-square-o"  title="<?=gettext('Add static mapping')?>" href="services_dhcp_edit.php?if=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['if'])?>&amp;mac=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['mac'])?>&amp;hostname=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['hostname'])?>"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
                        <a class="fa fa-plus-square" title="<?=gettext('Add WOL mapping')?>" href="services_wol_edit.php?if=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['if'])?>&amp;mac=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['mac'])?>&amp;descr=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['hostname'])?>"></a>
<?php if ($data['online'] != $online_string):?>
                        <a class="fa fa-power-off" title="<?=gettext('Send WOL packet')?>" href="services_wol.php?if=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['if'])?>&amp;mac=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['mac'])?>" usepost></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($data['type'] == $static_string): ?>
                        <a class="fa fa-pencil" title="<?=gettext('Edit static mapping')?>" href="services_dhcp_edit.php?if=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['if'])?>&amp;id=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['staticmap_array_index'])?>"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($data['type'] == $dynamic_string && $data['online'] != $online_string):?>
                        <a class="fa fa-trash" title="<?=gettext('Delete lease')?>" href="status_dhcp_leases.php?deleteip=<?=htmlspecialchars($data['ip'])?>&amp;all=<?=intval($_REQUEST['all'])?>" usepost></a>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php if ($no_leases_displayed): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="10"><?=gettext("No leases to display")?></td>
                </tr>
<?php
endif;
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title"><?=gettext('Lease Utilization')?></h2></div>
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed sortable-theme-bootstrap" data-sortable>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?=gettext('Interface')?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext('Pool Start')?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext('Pool End')?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext('Used')?></th>
                    <th><?=gettext('Capacity')?></th>
                    <th data-sortable="false" width="25%"><?=gettext('Utilization')?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php

if (count($dhcp_leases_subnet_counter)):
    ksort($dhcp_leases_subnet_counter);
    foreach ($dhcp_leases_subnet_counter as $listcounters):
        $now = $listcounters['count'];
        $max = ip_range_size_v4($listcounters['from'], $listcounters['to']);
        $per = (int)(($now / $max) * 100);

        /* determine the progress bar color class */
        foreach ([
           75 => 'progress-bar-success',
           90 => 'progress-bar-warning',
          100 => 'progress-bar-danger'] as $threshold => $class) {
            if ($per <= $threshold) {
                break;
            }
        }
?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$iflist[$listcounters['dhcpif']]?></td>
                    <td><?=$listcounters['from']?></td>
                    <td><?=$listcounters['to']?></td>
                    <td><?=$now?></td>
                    <td><?=$max?></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar <?=$class?> progress-bar-striped" aria-valuenow="<?=$now?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="<?=$max?>" style="width:<?=$per?>%"></div>
                        </div>
                        <span><?=sprintf(gettext('%s%% of %s'), $per, $max)?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<?php
    endforeach;
else:
?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6"><?=gettext('No leases are in use')?></td>
                </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if ($_REQUEST['all']): ?>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="status_dhcp_leases.php?all=0"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle icon-embed-btn"></i><?=gettext("Show Active and Static Leases Only")?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="status_dhcp_leases.php?all=1"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle icon-embed-btn"></i><?=gettext("Show All Configured Leases")?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
    <a class="btn btn-danger no-confirm" id="cleardhcp"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-embed-btn"></i><?=gettext("Clear All DHCP Leases")?></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
events.push(function() {
    // Make these controls plain buttons
    $("#btnsearch").prop('type', 'button');
    $("#btnclear").prop('type', 'button');

    // Search for a term in the entry name and/or dn
    $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
        var searchstr = $('#searchstr').val().toLowerCase();
        var table = $("#leaselist");
        var where = $('#where').val();

        table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
            var $tds    = $(this).find('td');
            var $popover    = $($.parseHTML($tds.eq(2).attr('data-content')));

            var lease    = $tds.eq(0).find('.act').eq(0).attr('title').trim().toLowerCase();
            var online   = $tds.eq(0).find('.online').eq(0).attr('title').trim().toLowerCase();
            var ipaddr   = $tds.eq(1).text().trim().toLowerCase();
            var macaddr  = $tds.eq(2).text().trim().toLowerCase();
            var clientid = $popover.closest('.cid').text().trim().toLowerCase();
            var hostname = $tds.eq(3).text().trim().toLowerCase();
            var descr    = $tds.eq(4).text().trim().toLowerCase();
            var start    = $tds.eq(5).text().trim().toLowerCase();
            var end      = $tds.eq(6).text().trim().toLowerCase();

            regexp = new RegExp(searchstr);
            if (searchstr.length > 0) {
                if (!(regexp.test(lease)    && ((where == 2) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(online)   && ((where == 3) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(ipaddr)   && ((where == 4) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(macaddr)  && ((where == 5) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(clientid) && ((where == 6) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(hostname) && ((where == 7) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(descr)    && ((where == 8) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(start)    && ((where == 9) || (where == 1))) &&
                    !(regexp.test(end)      && ((where == 10) || (where == 1)))
                    ) {
                    $(this).hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            } else {
                $(this).show(); // A blank search string shows all
            }
        });
    });

    // Clear the search term and unhide all rows (that were hidden during a previous search)
    $("#btnclear").click(function() {
        var table = $("#leaselist");

        $('#searchstr').val("");

        $('#where option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true);

        table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
            $(this).show();
        });
    });

    // Hitting the enter key will do the same as clicking the search button
    $("#searchstr").on("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#btnsearch").get(0).click();
        }
    });

    $('#cleardhcp').click(function() {
        if (confirm("<?=gettext('Are you sure you wish to clear all DHCP leases?')?>")) {
            postSubmit({cleardhcpleases: 'true'}, 'status_dhcp_leases.php');
        }
    });

});
//]]>
</script>

<?php
include('foot.inc');


What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

I have been poking around changing things to see if I get a different result. trying to break the functionality to see if I am in the right area.  Looked at the usort command and found a reference about swapping the a and b variables to try and reverse no success.  I see references to putting the leases in a file then putting the contents into an array.  I see 2 possible areas where I could possibly introduce a sort (low to high) that would give the results I want.  That's what I'll go back to when i have a chance.  I have test environment so i don't touch production.
